# c# console stick inside winform

Tags: c#, forms, console

I have a school project where i need to create a windows form application. But for my part i need to create a console application. Now i could open a console from a windows from through a button, and some code i did not fully understand.

1. But is it possible to open a console at the same time the win-form is opened.

2.Could the console be sticked on the win-form. ( like a image-box. you create somekind of area/box where the console stays inside.

1. How to "program" the console? and not through program.cs that is standard created in the project.

If you could help me out that would be great, been searching for days now...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you want to do with the console? Can you use a TextBox instead?

Comment: I can't it's a project for school. it's not what i want. I MUST use a console that starts from windows-form. (we have about 10 forms) and then show SQL data. ( the sql part is not a question, i already figured that out) Why am i getting down-votes. what is not good about my question?

Comment: You are being downvoted as "here's my homework problem, how do I solve it?" are not regarded as appropriate questions for stack overflow. They are the sort of questions you should be asking your teacher/tutor for help with.

Comment: And what when my teachers says "Search on the internet first, if you want my help i want to see your question posted on the internet"?

Comment: @KrijnvanderBurg: Then do that. https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+winforms+with+console

Comment: you're not looking with right questions, the first part, a console, could be a .exe file right.. you can open another program from your own, for the second part you can run your program in whatever position and wherever on screen you want.http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=c%2B%2B%20window%20size%20console&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cplusplus.com%2Fforum%2Fbeginner%2F1481%2F&ei=rnBuUrelNOiO5ASDk4CYBA&usg=AFQjCNGCOSWjOKxTtDU7XrXc9mX1FXPzDA&sig2=yC8bnD1WuEU7PW4EmQO7cw&bvm=bv.55123115,d.bGE

Comment: @KrijnvanderBurg: Yoor question is OK, but too basic to be here, if we help you you won't learn, look for a good tutorial or a book, and try to learn, not to solve your problem without understanding what is happening.

Comment: @tinyByte thank you, that might actually help. I sincerely thank you sir.

Comment: @KrijnvanderBurg, You are being helped. You are being given handy links to investigate. What you won't get is us spoon-feeding you the answer.

Comment: If you want learn you should solve the problem by searching possible examples online and books.  That means, figure out how can you use it in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ConsoleHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Allocates a new console for current process.
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Boolean AllocConsole();

    /// <summary>
    /// Frees the console.
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern Boolean FreeConsole();
}
```

You can call AllocConsole to create a console window, at which point you can read/write to it using the default Console methods. Then call FreeConsole when you're done.

Comment: Thank you, i found this code earlier too but in a way complexer type i would not understand. With Freeconsole you mean to let it close itself? and I am able to use console methods inside that class?

Comment: After you call AllocConsole you should just be able use standard Console methods built into the .Net framework.

Comment: Thank you very much, now i am capable of proceding further! Only if you want, do you know how to stick the console in the form? i mean, just as you create a image box with an image. Now you create a box which contains the console?

Comment: A simple search would yield you the answer. https://www.google.ca/search?q=window+within+window+C%23
You need to end up making the console window a child of a control (perhaps a panel) in the winforms application.

Answer (score 5):

Just change your project type (in Project Properties) to Console Project.
This will create a console when the program is launched.

You can manipulate the console using the normal methods in the `Console` class.

Comment: This is not a real answer to the question: "But is it possible to open a console at the same time the win-form is opened?".

Comment: I am working on this project with 30 other class members, Everything is windows-form. so starting up as a console is not an option sadly. But thank you for answering. I hope you might have a differnt solution

Answer (score 1):

Just create a WindowsFormsApplication as you create usually. Then just go to project properties and change the "WindowsFormsApplication" to "ConsoleApplication".

You're done with it. you can see the console appears as well as the `Form` if you have used `Application.Run(new MyForm())`

Comment: @caesay No problem. Myself too overlook on answers suddenly

Comment: I am working on this project with 30 other class members, Everything is windows-form, except my part. so starting up as a console is not an option sadly. it's only needed when a specific form is opened. Thank you for answering. hope you have another solution